# Angular_time filter

Tags: angularjs, time, filter

I want to make time filter which will show + if time is positive and - if time is negative (I have some calculations received from server),  and showing only hours and minutes.

I did folowing, please comment on how this could be better

```
timeClock.filter('signedDuration', function () {

return function (timespan) {

    if (timespan) {

        var hoursInDay = 24;

        var days = moment.duration(timespan).days();
        var hours = moment.duration(timespan).hours();
        var totalHours = (days * hoursInDay + hours);
        totalHours = totalHours > 0 ? "+"  + totalHours
                                    : totalHours;
        var minutes = moment.duration(timespan).minutes();
        minutes = minutes < 0 ? Math.abs(minutes)
                              : minutes;
        var output = '';

        output += totalHours + 'h ';
        output += minutes + 'm';

        return output;
    }
};
});
```

Comment: By `negative` time, you mean a date in the past, and `positive` time is a date in the future?

Comment: well yes, i don't have past and future just some calculation, but i did already something and updated my question